# getting context.connectionId for signalr in an ASP.NET post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I have an app were there is a process to upload excel files and update my database with their contents but sometimes the files are so large, the process takes more than 230 seconds, and azure returns a 500 server error. My plan to get around this is to have the app open a signalR connection on upload and then provide updates to a progress bar while it works through the file. Problem is, I can't seem to get basic signalR functionality up and running. When I try to get the connectionId from Context, I get a null value because Context is null. I've tried everything I can find in forums and tutorials to get to the bottom of this, but no luck.

Here is the code from my StartUp.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(LIMS.Startup))] //maybe this is needed
//[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(LIMS.Startup))]
namespace LIMS
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            ConfigureSignalR(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a Startup.SignalR.cs file in my App_Start folder with the following code:

```
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LIMS
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

my cshtml file looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LabSampleImport";
}

<h2>Lab Sample Import</h2>

<h3 class="text-warning">@ViewBag.Message @TempData["Message"]</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("LabSampleImport", "LabData", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <span><input type="file" name="file" style="display:inline" /></span>
    <p>
        Use the Button above to select the Excel file on your hard drive with the lab sample information you wish to add and/or edit.
        Once you have selected the correct file, click the "Upload Selected File" button below to initiate the import. When the import is complete,
        a file with the same name will download back to your device through your browser. There will be a comment column in the file to indicate the result of each lab sample/row.
    </p>
    <span><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Upload Selected File" class="btn btn-default" /></span>
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Download a Template" class="btn btn-default" />

}


<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    theHub.client.initProgressBar = function () {
        alert("The server has just informed this webpage that a progress bar should be displayed.");
    }

    theHub.client.updateProgressBar = function (percentage) {
        alert("The server has just informed this webpage that a progress bar should be updated.");
    }

    theHub.client.clearProgressBar = function (percentage) {
        alert("The server has just informed this webpage that a progress bar should be cleared.");
    }
</script>
```

My ProgressHub.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace LIMS.Hubs
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        public void NotifyStart(string connectionId)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).initProgressBar();
        }
        public void NotifyProgress(string connectionId, int percentage)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).updateProgressBar(percentage);
        }
        public void NotifyEnd(string connectionId)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).clearProgressBar();
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller method that is giving me the error because Context is null looks like this:

```
// POST: LabData/LabSampleImport
[HttpPost, ActionName("LabSampleImport")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "canAddSamples")]
public async Task<ActionResult> LabSampleImportOption(HttpPostedFileBase file, string submitButton)
{
    if (submitButton == "Upload Selected File")
    {
        //upload file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            ProgressHub hub1 = new ProgressHub();
            //This is where Context is inexplicably null
            var connectionId = hub1.Context.ConnectionId;
            //and this is where app goes kaplooey due to a null reference exception
            hub1.NotifyStart(connectionId);

            // A bit of placeholder work
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            hub1.NotifyProgress(connectionId, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Every other post I have found with a similar issue seemed to be centered around the order in which the startup file does ConfigureAuth(app) and app.MapSignalR(). I'm confident this isn't the issue here but still at a loss for why Context is null. I've considered just getting the connectionID on the client side and passing it to the method but since the controller method is called from the button in the form post, I don't see a way of making razor set a connectionID parameter in the post instructions when the connection Id can't be determined until later in the game. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple way, you could store the current connection id (`$.connection.hub.id`) within a hidden input and leverage the [jQuery Form](https://github.com/jquery-form/form) to submit the form with AJAX without refreshing your current page which would return your a new connection id. You need to modify your view page as follows:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <span><input type="file" name="file" style="display:inline" /></span>

    <!--add the hidden input for storing the current connection Id-->
    <input type="hidden" name="connectionId" id="connectionId"/>

    <span><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Upload Selected File" class="btn btn-default" /></span>
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Download a Template" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

**javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var chat = $.connection.progressHub;

    chat.client.initProgressBar = function () {
        console.log("The server has just informed this webpage that a progress bar should be displayed.");
    }

    chat.client.updateProgressBar = function (percentage) {
        console.log("current uploading process:" + percentage + "%");
    }

    chat.client.clearProgressBar = function (percentage) {
        console.log("The server has just informed this webpage that a progress bar should be cleared.");
    }

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        var cid = $.connection.hub.id;
        $("#connectionId").val(cid);
        console.log("connection Id:" + cid);
    });

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        complete: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

**Action for uploading the file:**

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string submitButton, string connectionId)
{
    ProgressHub.NotifyStart(connectionId);

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ProgressHub.NotifyProgress(connectionId, 20);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ProgressHub.NotifyProgress(connectionId, 50);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ProgressHub.NotifyProgress(connectionId, 100);

    return Json("Done", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**TEST:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It didn't occur to me that I could just use AJAX to submit the form after determining the connection ID on the client side. I ran into a little trouble with the implementation of this approach. In my controller method, I wasn't able to compile the code as written. I got the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field..." so I got around that issue by adding the line progressHub hub = new progressHub(); and then  hub.NotifyStart(connectionId); I also had to change the case of my hub so that it started with a lower case letter due to some js issue. Thanks again.

Comment: I marked the methods under `ProgressHub`  as static.

Comment: I also had some issues with getting the jquery and signalr script libraries loaded just right in my cshtml file. Lots of wierd bugs in my JS console where jQuery or $ would be undefined. I still wonder why Context.ConnectionId was null in the first place and I had to do all this work on the client side.

Comment: I used https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js. You need to check the jquery version you used. You just created a new instance via `new ProgressHub()`. Moreover, you could also [Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

Comment: You could also follow [Getting Started with SignalR 2 and MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).